FileHandler is not registering
I am currently working on FileHandlers and I followed official document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/file-handlers/?view=odsp-graph-online .But the custom button does not appear on the screen even if I waited for more than 24 hours (the cache timeout). Here is my manifest
I tried to reset the file handler cache from following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/file-handlers/reset-cache?view=odsp-graph-online#calling-the-forcerefresh-method-for-end-users .However I got invalidAudienceUri error all the time.
How to get the correct bearer token for the resetting file handler cache?
